# How can I remove UNC password from a file

Tags: iis, unc

Hi we have an mp4 file on our web server in a virtual directory

When we try to access the file we get prompted for a username/password.
When I tried to change the path of the virtual directory I got the message 'The following child nodes also define the value of the "UNCPassword" property, which overrides the value you have just set ...' which included the mp4 file that we try to access.

How can I remove the UNC Password securing the file?
The file is not on a shared drive its on the same drive as the web site root.

The funny thing is the path of the virtual directory is not a UNC path it's a full path on the same server d:.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding an AnonymousUserPass to the meta data file using The IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17275